# BadgeValue not working on moreTableView of TabBarController for iOS 5 (works fine on iOS 6)

Tags: ios5, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, tabbarcontroller

I have a badgeValue for a ViewController thats shown inside MORE tableview. It works fine on iOS 6 but doesnt work at al with iOS 5 or below.

I am setting the badgeValue of the tabBarItem to set the value to be shown.

Can anyone kindly suggest what to do ?

Thanks